# Firebase - Push Notifications

Tags: android, ios, firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I just started the firebase get started tutorial on sending push notifications. Is it possible to query for all the push notifications that are out on firebase when the app opens?

Here is the quick start guide I am using:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/notifications/android/console-audience

I am not able to find a reference to query the notifications like Parse had.

Comment: notifications are not meant to be queried. If you have information for the user it should be stored on a server and then when the app opens you should check your server for new messages

Comment: I assumed as much. I am fairly new to mobile dev. I will create a collection that holds the notifications. Thanks for your help. Just thought I would ask in case I was missing something!